# Validation of a certificate chain when opening a SSLSocket in Java

Tags: java, ssl

**My Setup**

My goal is to set up a SSL/TLS secured connection (explicit) with an FTP-Server.
The appropriate Root CA Certificate is stored in a Truststore called `truststore.jks`.
After the `AUTH TLS`command I'm using the following code to build up the SSLSocket.

```
public SSLSocket enterSecureMode(Socket s) throws Exception {
        KeyStore truststore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        truststore.load(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("truststore.jks")), "mypass".toCharArray());

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(truststore);

        SSLContext sCon = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sCon.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sCon.getSocketFactory();
        return (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(s, "<HOSTNAME>", 21, true);
}
```

The code itself is running fine and I received a secured Socket-Connection, but I wonder whether this can stand attacks like e.g MITM or not. I mean would that program discover an attempt of somebody trying to 'give me a Fake-Certificate'.
Therefore I'd be very happy if some more experienced SSL-Network-Programmers could enlight me :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sufficient. The attacker would have to provide a certificate signed by the root CA. However you don't need all this code: you only need

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "truststore.jks");
SSLContext sCon = SSLContext.getDefault();
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sCon.getSocketFactory();
return (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(s, "<HOSTNAME>", 21, true)
```

If you want to be totally paranoid, after creating the `SSLSocket` you can get the `SSLSession` and then the peer certificate chain and make sure that the zeroth entry exactly matches the exact server's certificate, but this step is mostly omitted.

Comment: Let's assume I'm paranoid about security (mainly because I want the maximum of protection for my programs/data). Would I have to store maybe the fingerprint of the Servers Certificate and check if they match or not when starting a SSL-Connection?

Comment: Yes, you could do that, or indeed store the entire certificate and compare it bitwise. But if you did either of those things you would have to update it every expiry. Provided it is signed by the correct root CA and has the same Subject Distinguished Name, which the root CA is obliged to verify, it can be trusted.